# Automated cross-account DB backup using AWS Lambda,RDS,SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I have a Lambda function that shares an RDS manual snapshot with another AWS account.

I am trying to create a 'chain reaction' where the lambda is executed in the 1st account , then the snapshot is visible to the 2nd account, and another lambda is triggered that copies the visible snapshot in another region (inside the 2nd account) .

I tried using RDS event subscriptions and SNS topics, but I noticed that there is no RDS event subscription for sharing and/or modifying a RDS snapshot.

Then, I tried to setup cross-account permissions so the lambda from the first account will publish to an SNS topic which will trigger the lambda in the second account, but it seems that the topic and the target lambda must be in the same region (however the code that copies the db snapshot must be in the target region) . I followed [this guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns-create-x-account-permissions.html) and I end up with this error:

`A client error (InvalidParameter) occurred when calling the Subscribe operation: Invalid parameter: TopicArn`

Has anyone tried something like this?

Is cross-region communication eventually feasible?

Could I trigger something in one region from something in another (any AWS service is welcome)?

My next attempts will be:

1. cross-region lambda invocation
2. Make use of API Gateway

Comment: API Gateway will definitely solve your cross-region calling problem, but not much else. Are you able to "see" your snapshot from the 2nd region? If yes, you could try SQS to message exchange instead of SNS, but I don't know if cross-region limitation would apply too.

Comment: Thanks @jfneis, I think I am going to try API Gateway. It seems a better match with Lambda

Comment: definitely. We are using API Gateway with SQS and it works, but a bunch of features/steps are not well documented yet. Lambda it the main use case for API Gateway, so I think you'll do fine.